# Symfony 3.4 - updating entity after soft-deleting related entity row

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I've got an entity called `Logs` that has a ManyToOne relation to an `HourlyRates` entity. Both `Logs` and `HourlyRates` have date properties. When adding a `log` with a specific date, an `hourlyRate` is assigned to it if the log-date fits within the rate's time range. I'm using the Doctrine Extensions Bundle, so the data in each entity can be soft-deleted.

**What needs to be done:** 
After soft-deleting an `HourlyRate` the related `Log` has to be updated, so that the nearest existing past `HourlyRate` takes the place of the deleted one.

I tried to use `preSoftDelete`, `postSoftDelete`, `preRemove` and `postRemove` methods inside an `HourlyRate` entity listener. The code was being executed and the setters were working properly, but the database hasn't been updated in any of said cases. An "EntityNotFoundException" was being thrown everytime.

My second approach was to use the `preRemove` event along with setting the `cascade` option to "all" by using annotations in the `HourlyRate` class. As a result, soft-deleting an `hourlyRate` caused soft-deleting of the related `log`.

The Log entity:

```php
class Log
{
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\HourlyRate", inversedBy="logs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $hourlyRate;

    public function setHourlyRate(?HourlyRate $hourlyRate): self
    {
        $this->hourlyRate = $hourlyRate;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The HourlyRate entity:

```php
class HourlyRate
{
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    //other code
        /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Log", mappedBy="hourlyRate", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $logs;
}
```

The HourlyRate entity listener:

```php
class HourlyRateEntityListener
{

     public function preRemove(HourlyRate $hourlyRate, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
     {
         $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

         /** @var HourlyRateRepository $HRrepo */
         $HRrepo = $entityManager->getRepository(HourlyRate::class);

         foreach ($hourlyRate->getLogs() as $log)
         {
             $rate = $HRrepo->findHourlyRateByDate($log->getDate(), $log->getUser(), $hourlyRate);
             $log->setHourlyRate($rate);
         }

     }
}
```

The repository method:

```php
class HourlyRateRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function findHourlyRateByDate(?\DateTimeInterface $datetime, User $user, ?HourlyRate $ignore = null): ?HourlyRate
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('hr')
            ->where('hr.date <= :hr_date')
            ->andWhere('hr.user = :user')
            ->orderBy('hr.date', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->setParameters(array('hr_date' => $datetime, 'user' => $user));

        //ignore the "deleted" hourlyRate
        if($ignore){
            $qb->andWhere('hr.id != :ignored')
            ->setParameter('ignored', $ignore->getId());
        }

        return $qb->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any of your help.

**EDIT:**

Okay so after a whole week of trials and errors i finally managed to achieve the result I wanted.

I removed the One-To-Many relation between the `hourlyRates` and the `logs` from the entities, but left the `$hourlyRate` property inside the `Log` class. Then I got rid of the `HourlyRateEntityListener` and the `preRemove()` method from the `LogEntityListener`. Instead, I implemented the `postLoad()` method:

```php
class LogEntityListener
{
    public function postLoad(Log $log, LifeCycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
        $HRrepo = $entityManager->getRepository(HourlyRate::class);

        /** @var HourlyRateRepository $HRrepo */
        $rate = $HRrepo->findHourlyRateByDate($log->getDate(), $log->getUser());

        $log->setHourlyRate($rate);
    }
}
```

This approach allows me to set the proper `hourlyRate` for each `log` without involving the database. Idk if this solution is acceptable though.

Comment: Why dont you just query the past `hourlyRate` and call `setHourlyRate` on your `Log`?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing inside the listener.

Comment: Then you should find out why the `EntityNotFoundException` exception is thrown. It means that you try to query an non existent entity. So your query returns no result.
Is there actually a next hourlyRate in the database which matches your condition?
Also if you are using [Gedmos soft deletable](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html) you shouldnt have to manually check for soft deleted entities but just register the filter.

Comment: The filter is already registered in the config. When I was testing every approach, I made sure that there is an existing hourlyRate that should fit the conditions. The exception is thrown because the deleted rate is not being overwritten with a new one. The program tries to get the old rate, but it can't since it was soft-deleted. If the data was updated properly, that problem wouldn't occur (IMO).

Comment: Have you `flush()`ed your entity manager after deleting the `houerlyRate`?
From the docs:
`Just like persist, invoking remove on an entity does NOT cause an immediate SQL DELETE to be issued on the database. The entity will be deleted on the next invocation of EntityManager#flush() that involves that entity.`

Comment: Using `flush()` inside the listener's methods was causing some kind of an infinite loop. I have dealt with the problem in a different (and probably messier) way. Thank you very much for your replies!